# Transformation of a Random Variable; issues deriving CDF

Tags: probability

[image: Problem]

I'm confused on how they got the CDF of Y. My process would be:
P(Y≤y)

P(X²≤y)

P(X ≤ ±√y)

P(-√y ≤ X ≤ √y)

P(X ≤ √y) - P(X ≤ -√y)

Fx(√y) - Fx(-√y)

for finding the CDF. Where did I go wrong here? Is there no -√y because of the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process has an invalid step. It is *not correct* to take square roots of both sides of an inequality.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How would I go about getting X by itself then if I can't square root both sides?

Comment: I don't think that part's invalid.

Comment: There are a couple of fumbles in the middle part, but in the end what you wrote on the last line is correct. It's equivalent to what they wrote above. Just use the definition of $F_X$ to simplify it a little more.

Comment: Oh right I forgot about that. That works, thanks.